# Valid data for imshow

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I want to create a new image with numpy, the image that i want to create is this:[image]

But when run my script to show the image show me something like this:
[image]

Doesn't show the semicircle and send a message that says **"Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers)."**

My code is this:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

new_image = np.zeros((300, 250, 3))

for x in range(300):
    for y in range(250):
        if (180 <= x <= 240) and (100 <= y <=200):
            new_image[x, y , 2] = 255
        elif (90 <= x <= 150) and ((-2*x/3)+110 <= y <= (2*x/3)-10):
            new_image[x,y,0] = 255
        elif (60 <= x <=120) and (150 <= y <= 200+math.sqrt(900-(x-90)^2)):
            new_image[x,y,0] = 255
            new_image[x,y,1] = 255
        else:
            new_image[x,y,0] = 255
            new_image[x,y,1] = 255
            new_image[x,y,2] = 255


# First Plot
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(new_image)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `plt.imshow((new_image).astype(np.uint8))` should remove the warning. Can you explain your reasoning behind `elif (60 <= x <=120) and (150 <= y <= 200+math.sqrt(900-(x-90)^2)):`?

Comment: Note that `^` in python means `XOR` - if you want to raise some x to the power of 2, use `x ** 2`.

Comment: @Jeppe it's because that's the equation of the figure, we do the same in Matlab but we need to pass the code to python but in Python doesn't show the semicircle.

Comment: @Jeppe thanks I forgot to change that. Now works.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `scikit-learn` or `scipy` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed & replaced with `matplotlib`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, new_image is an array of floats, but when you assign the color values, you need to give between 0 and 1, but you are giving 255 which is an int.

you could give int (0-255) for color values but your image array should be be made of ints.

so you can get rid of the error by using

```
new_image = np.zeros((300, 250, 3), dtype = int)
```